# Gamepad issues in Windows

Tags: controllers, windows, assassins-creed-unity, valkyria-chronicles

Had anyone ever encountered an issue when playing with a 360 (I'm using a Razer Sabertooth) gamepad in Windows where one or both of the sticks seems like it's pushing upwards slightly?
The issue appears only in certain games but is constant rather than intermittent in those games.
I get it in both Assassin's Creed Unity (but not Black Flag) where the camera pushes up above Arnot all the time (but I can easily move it back) and also in Valkyria Chronicles where I can't even get past the menu as the highlighted menu item scrolls as if the left stick were jammed all the way up.
I've tried different USB ports and the like with no success. I'm not aware of any separate drivers that can be installed (razer don't seem to have any and windows treats it as a standard 360 controller). The bit that really fries my noodle is that it works perfectly in other games!

Comment: Have you tried calibrating the controller?

Comment: About controller calibration, this might be useful: http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/calibrate-controller-for-windows-pc